# How can I change the date format of the backup display in Time Machine?

Tags: time-machine

Currently, the Time Machine display from System Preferences shows this:

```
Oldest backup: 2021-25-10
Latest backup: Today, 17:13
Next backup: Today, 19:09
```

The 'Oldest backup' format is particularly confusing - it would be much more intuitive if it used a format like YYYY-MM-DD instead of YYYY-DD-MM. Is it configurable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out - this is controlled here:

System Preferences -> Language & Region -> Advanced -> Dates

In particular, the "Long" format determines this particular display.